# How to Casting DataSource to List<T>?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, casting, datasource

I have the following method that load products on a DataGridView

```
private void LoadProducts(List<Product> products)
{
    Source.DataSource = products;  // Source is BindingSource
    ProductsDataGrid.DataSource = Source;
}
```

And now I'm trying to give me back to save them as shows below.

```
private void SaveAll()
{
   Repository repository = Repository.Instance;
   List<object> products = (List<object>)Source.DataSource; 
   Console.WriteLine("Este es el número {0}", products.Count);
   repository.SaveAll<Product>(products);
   notificacionLbl.Visible = false;
}
```

But I get an `InvalidCastException` on this line:

```
List<object> products = (List<object>)Source.DataSource;
```

So how can I cast the DataSource to an List?

Comment: What exactly does the exception say?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't cast covariantly directly to List;

Either:

```
List<Product> products = (List<Product>)Source.DataSource;
```

or:

```
List<Object> products = ((List<Product>)Source.DataSource).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: For Line `List<Object> products = ((List<Product>)Source.DataSource).Cast<object>();`
Cannot implicitly type 'System.COllections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>' to 'System.COllections.Generic.List<object>. An explicit convertion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You need a .ToList() at the end, my bad!

Answer (score 6):

> So how can I cast the DataSource to an List?

You have plenty of options

```
var products = (List<Product>)Source.DataSource; // products if of type List<Product>
```

or

```
 List<Object> products = ((IEnumerable)Source.DataSource).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

or

```
List<Object>  products = ((IEnumerable)Source.DataSource).OfType<object>().ToList();
```

or

```
List<Object> products = new List<Object>();
((IEnumerable)Source.DataSource).AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach( x => products.Add( (object)x));
```

Comment: `DataSource` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, so you'll need to cast it to that first.

Comment: Same problem.  `AsEnumerable` is an extension method of `IEnumerable`, not `object`.

Comment: Removed the last way. I was wondering How `Cast<>` can work and `AsEnumerable` cannot, while both accept `IEnumerable` as input?

Comment: Neither can work, that's what I'm saying.  You need to do `((IEnumerable)Source.DataSource).Cast<object>()` or `OfType`.  `DataSource` is of type `object` not `IEnumerable<object>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your List ist of type `List<Product>` which is different from `List<object>`. Try to cast to `List<Product>`

Answer (score 0):

Convining the answers This is my solution:

```
private void SaveAll()
{
    Repository repository = Repository.Instance;
    List<Product> products = (List<Product>)Source.DataSource;
    IEnumerable<object> objects = products.Cast<object>();
    repository.SaveAll<Product>(objects.ToList<object>());
    notificacionLbl.Visible = false;
}
```

I accept constructive criticisms.

Comment: what exactly is the input parameter type of SaveAll<Product>? are you sure you need a List<object>?

Comment: The idea is that `SaveAll<T>(List<object>)` is generic, so I will calling this method for all persistent objects. Products, Vendors, Makers, etc.

Comment: then it would make more sense if the signature is `SaveAll<T>(List<T> ...`, or even better `SaveAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> ...`.